# WPF MenuItem Vertical Alignment

Tags: wpf

My questions are:

1. How can I make the menu icons larger than normal for the visually impaired?
2. How can I vertically align the text within the menu bar?

Below is the code I've used so far, but I can't make it to work (larger images/fonts) and vertical alignment.

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" Height="48" x:Name="menuMain" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" >
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>

    <Menu.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF3A60AD" Offset="0.528"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6A85D8" Offset="0.01"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF3464C4" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF202E7E" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Menu.Background>

    <Menu.BitmapEffect>
        <DropShadowBitmapEffect />
    </Menu.BitmapEffect>

    <MenuItem x:Name="Exit" Header="Exit" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Click="Exit_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Exit Bug Off">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\exit48.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem x:Name="Tracker" Header="_Tracker" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Orange" FontSize="16" Click="Tracker_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Tracker">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\tracker48.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>

        <MenuItem Command="New" />
        <MenuItem Command="Search" />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem x:Name="WIR" Header="_WIR" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="LightGreen" FontSize="16" Click="WIR_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="WIR">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\wir48.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem x:Name="Report" Header="_Report" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Pink" FontSize="16" Click="Report_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Report">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\report48.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem x:Name="Admin" Header="_Admin" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="LightBlue" FontSize="16" Click="Admin_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Admin">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\admin48.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define menu item's `Header` like this, you have full control over the font/image size and their alignment.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="Report" Click="Report_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Report">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="C:\Dropbox\Development\BugOff\BugOff\Resources\report48.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
            <AccessText Foreground="Pink" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center">_Report</AccessText>
        </StackPanel>
    </MenuItem.Header>                
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kindness in responding to my question... It was spot on... I tried to vote you up, but it didn't accept it... Anyway, you are 10 out of 10...